# How to bind data to Multiple listViews in TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following:

1) I have a TabbedPage which contain multiple Tabs.
2) Each Tab contains a page which has ListView 
3) The data for each of ListView in each Tab base on a single Json result from REST service

Problem:

At where I should call and consume the Json REST web service and how to bind the data to each of the ListView?

```
say, at Code Behind of TabbedPage.xaml.cs

I start to call the Json Web service

var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();  

var response = await client.GetAsync("Http://Rest WebService"); 

string GeneralJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  

GeneralClassforJsonList ObjGeneralList = new GeneralClassForJsonList();  

if (GeneralJson != "")  
 {  

     ObjGeneralList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeneralClassforJsonList>(generalList);  
}  


  var Product = ObjectGeneralList.Result.Products

  var Service = ObjectGeneralList.Result.Services
```

I would like to know How to Binding the data to each of the listviews respectively 
in product and service pages:

listviewProduct.ItemsSource = Product

listviewService.ItemsSource = Service

**Update(1): Approach 1**

```
In TabbedPage, it has 2 or more tab.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:SembIWIS.View"  
       x:Class="myApp.MainPage">

  <local:ProductPage>
  </local:ProductPage>

  <local:ServicePage>
  </local:ServicePage>

</TabbedPage>


1) 
I created a static Class in Model to store Json Result in string 

public static class ProductServiceJson
    {
        public static string StrProductServiceJson;
    }

2) 
In TabbedPage.xaml.cs (Code Behind)

 public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
 {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
       //- code here not execute.

       //I start to call the REST api 

      var response = await client.GetAsync("Http://Rest WebService"); 
      string GeneralJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  

      ProductServiceJson.StrProductServiceJson = GeneralJson;

     }
 }

3) 
public partial class Product : ContentPage
 {
    public Product()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetUpListData();
    }


    private void SetUpListData()
    {
       //-- code 
      // how come code here will be executed but not code in tabbedPage.xaml.cs?

    }
}
```

**Problem:**

1) Why code in TabbedPage.xaml.cs not execute but code in Product.xaml.cs (code behind of Product.xaml)?

2) When code excuted in Product.xaml.cs, the StrProductService is empty or null since web service call in TabbedPage.xaml.cs

3) Will code in Service.xaml.cs be executed?

4) What is the order of execution for TabbedPage, I mean which Tab will have the first execution and if there are 6 tabs?

TIA

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/

Comment: I don't get what is the question. You have 2 options: 1.use one model for the parent TabbedPage and your tabs can access it. 2. Pass the same model to each tab page. Model should have JSON response required. After you parse JSON in model to list of objects populate your lists using ItemsSource. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Yuri, My problem is how to pass the data (as in my code ) from deserializing the Json result using JsonConvert inTabbedPage's code behind to each of the Tab base on your approach 1 and 2. Can you show me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. I didn't test that code, just wrote to give you an idea.

```
class ObjGeneral 
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<ObjGeneral> MyList{get;set;}
}
```

Then in page code

```
var myViewModel=new MyViewModel();
//populate your list
myViewModel.MyList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjGeneral>>(generalList);
BindingContext=myViewModel;
```

Then in xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="toggleListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Label x:Name="lblPlaceName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Comment: please refer to my approach 1. How to handle the code execution in TabbedPage and the Page it contains?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Have you solved what you wanted to do? Or you want to clarify the question?